# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSArray

Tags: java, pdfbox

`ClassCastException` occured at highlighted row, any idea?

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(sourcePDF);
doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);

PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm form = docCatalog.getAcroForm(); 
PDXFA xfa = form.getXFA();
COSBase cos = xfa.getCOSObject();
**COSStream coss = (COSStream) cos;**
```

Comment: If you are surprised that that PDF object can be an array, look at the specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), Table 218 – Entries in the interactive form dictionary – says "**XFA** stream or array".

Comment: was your query resolved with below answer?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `xfa.getCOSObject()` is returning a `COSArray` but you are casting it to `COSStream`. Should be

```
COSArray coss = (COSArray) cos;
```